# encode method for UTF16 and UTF32 in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-16, utf-32

I want to investigate how do UTF16 and UTF32 work by looking specific characters in binary.

I know we can user
`"string".encoding("(encoding name)")` to check its hex value in specific encoding and it works fine with UTF8.

but when it comes to UTF16 or 32, I found the result is different from the encodnig value it supposed to be.

for example, the first letter "あ" in Japanese, accordting to https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3042
the hex value of UTF8,16,32 are
E38182, 3042, 00003042

so if I execute the following code

```
print("あ".encode('utf-8'))
print("あ".encode('utf-16BE'))
print("あ".encode('utf-32BE'))
```

I will get

```
b'\xe3\x81\x82'
b'0B'
b'\x00\x000B'
```

as you can see, utf8 is identical with the code table, but 16 and 32 are wired...
No idea how can 000B convert to 3042, do I misunderstand something of the encode method?

Comment: `0B` does not mean `\x0b`. It's `\x30\x42` decoded as ASCII for display.

Comment: ah....I got it....thank you very much, I want to give you best answer but it is comment haha

Comment: Use `b'0B'.hex()` to view the hexadecimal value of the bytes.